# MAAS and ISCSI SAN

Tags: maas, storage, iscsi

I have 3 servers, I am deploying one as MAAS controller I also have a Dell MD3000i storage which connect via network.
The goal is
1) 1 Server for MAAS CONTROLLER
2) 2 servers to host virtual machine
3) Using ISCSI NAS to save virtual machines or any data related and be shared between 2 host servers.

The questions, how can i use MAAS to deploy ISCSI NAS storage to be shared between 2 server that they will run virtual machines?

Let me know if you need more information or I am missing anything.

Regards.

JP.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if MAAS can directly configure NAS as it uses only things it can find during commissioning. I would use post deploy script in your case. It will be fired by MAAS and it can mount your remote disks to proper places